# R Not able to install CHAID

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am trying to install CHAID package into R using the command below.

*install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")*

I keep getting the response

*Error in dev.off() : could not find function "dev.off"
Execution halted
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘CHAID’ had non-zero exit status*

The OS is Windows10. R is running the latest 3.5.1

I tried to google the error and find a fix but without success.

Comment: Have you installed R in C drive? if yes make sure you have administrator privileges .it might be the case

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the `partykit` package installed first before installing `CHAID`. That worked for me.

Comment: partykit package was installed. Thanks

Comment: Not a solution to THIS problem; but I started exploring rpart library as a possible alternative. So far it is serving my purpose.